# Jquery button doesn't submit a request

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#manage').click(function() {
      swal({
          title: 'Choose your settings',
          type: 'info',
          html:"<form method='post' id='set'>{% csrf_token %}<input type='text' class='set-pref' placeholder='Enter your preference' name='input_val' id='settings'><button name='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm f-14 mr-1' type='button'>Set</button></form>",
          showCloseButton: false,
          showCancelButton: false,
          focusConfirm: false,
          confirmButtonText: 'Confirm',
          cancelButtonText: 'Go forward',
      });
    });
});
</script>

<button name="button" id="manage" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm f-14 mr-1">manage</button>
```

When the button is hit, a panel shows. The problem is that the form inside the panel is not being submitted by the button. When i fill the input field and hit the button, nothing happens. Changing the button to `type='submit'` won't work either, because it will just refresh the page without submitting anything. I'm sure the problem is inside my previous block of code, but here is how i'm sending the request anyway:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#set").submit(function (event) {

      callAJAX(viewsurl,
       {"X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") },
       parameters={'settings': $('#settings').val()},

      'post',
       function(data){


       }, null, null );
  return false; 
  });

});

</script>
```

Comment: `callAJAX(viewsurl,` doesn't talk much, is `viewsurl` a correct path, what does console network says? Have you tried to `console.log( some, variable, here )` and there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems that you're dynamically creating a FORM that is still not existent on the page via Laravel's Swal `html:`.

My suggestion is to dynamically assign your handler using the `.on()` method:

```
jQuery(function ($) { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

  $(document).on('submit', '#set', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent browser submit form

    callAJAX(
       viewsurl,
       {"X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken")},
       parameters={'settings': $('#settings').val()},
       'post',
       function(data){
         // joy joy
       },
       null,
       null
     );
  });

});
```

and make sure to use

```
....type='submit'>Set</butt....
```

Comment: Awesome! I had a vague idea that the problem was something like that, since all the other forms in the page worked. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Is it possible that the POST request is not receiving the value of the id 'settings' for the same reason? I've tried it and the function receives a blank value from the form!

Comment: @Jack022 I don't know how that `callAJAX` function works, and what should  `parameters={'settings': $('#settings').val()` exactly be. Perhaps you want to simply send formData ? Or a serialized form? Have you tried to instead of `parameters={'settings': $('#settings').val()}` simply use the actual object `{'settings': $('#settings').val()}`

Comment: To answer your question, no, since the `$('#settings')` element will be queried in the DOM on submit - at that point that element exists, no worries about that.

Comment: It was an error on my side :). Thank you a lot again!